# Why do all of my latex figures say "chesches" next to it?

Tags: floats

When I use \includegraphics all of my figures say "chesches" at the bottom left of the figure.

Here is the code:

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width = 6 inches]{HHCircuit.png}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You should specify `6in`, not `6 inches`

Comment: use `in` not `inches`

Answer (score 2):

Use `in` not `inches`:

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width = 6in]{HHCircuit.png}
\end{figure}
```